# mlflow track tensorflow dense size

Tags: tensorflow, mlflow

I'm using keras-tuner for hyperparameter tuning.

I tried track mlflow with `mlflow.tensorflow.autolog()` but I can't see Dense layer size.

How can I track Dense layer size with mlflow?